# Rails nested query with has many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have following model association:

```rb
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      # It has columns `status` its value is 'active' for active and 'disabled' for inactive
    end
    
    class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :team_users
     has_many :users, through: :team_users, source: :user
    end
    
    class TeamUser < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :team
    end
```

Now, How can I find teams that have at least one active team user or with a user having status 'active'.

I am hoping something like:

```rb
Team.includes(team_users: :user).where(team_users: {user: {status: 'active'} })
```

Note: Team does not need all the users to be active but at least one user should be active on team_user.

Comment: `Team.joins(:users).where(users: { status: 'active' })`?

Comment: `users` can't be joined directly to the team because its relation is through team_user.

Comment: It gives `Can't join 'Team' to association named 'users'; perhaps you misspelled it?` error message.

Comment: Hmm, don't you have `has_many :users` on your `Team` model?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I understood sth. wrong, but a query like this should do the job easily:

```
@active_teams = Team.where(id: User.where(status: "active"))
```